# Rock, paper, lizard, spock. User has to input 100 games and it program should give the outcome of how many of each were choosen

Tags: java

I got this code from youtube, but I don't know how to ask the user to input 100 games and show the outcome of how many of each were used.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperSissors {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    String choice = console.nextLine();

    if (isValid(choice)){
        int aIChoice = (int)(Math.random()*3);
        int personChoice = getVal(choice);
        System.out.println("You picked " + choice);
        System.out.println("The computer picked " + getAIChoice(aIChoice));
        System.out.println("You " + didPersonWin(personChoice, aIChoice));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid input!");
    }
}
public static String getAIChoice(int x){
    if (x == 0){
        return "Rock";
    }
    if (x ==1){
        return "Paper";
    }
    if (x == 2){
        return "Scissors";
    }
    return null;
}
public static String didPersonWin(int pChoice, int computerChoice){
    if (pChoice == 0){
        if (computerChoice != 1){
            if (computerChoice != 0){
                return "WIN" ;
            }
            return "Tie";
        }
        return "Lose";
    }
    if (pChoice == 1){
        if (computerChoice != 2){
            if (computerChoice != 1){
                return "WIN";
            }
            return "Tie";
        }
        return "Lose";
    }
    if (computerChoice != 0){
        if (computerChoice != 2){
            return "Win";
        }
        return "Tie";
    }
    return "Lose";
}
public static boolean isValid(String string){
    if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
        return true;
    }
     if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
        return true;
    }
     if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")){
         return true;
     }
        return false;
}
public static int getVal(String string){
    if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")){
        return 0;
    }
    if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: 1) You should start with a Java tutorial. 2) Letting others to do your work packaging in a question is not welcomed here.

Comment: 3) The title should be the problem you're having, not the requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int x = 0;
        int rock = 0;
        int paper = 0;
        int scissors = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            x = rand.nextInt(3);
            if (x == 1) {
                rock += 1;
            } else if (x == 2) {
                paper += 1;
            } else {
                scissors += 1;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Rock = " + rock + "\nPaper = " + paper + "\nScissors = " + scissors);
    }
}
```

This code will simply run it 100 times of rock paper scissors and output the results of each outcome.

Comment: Thank you so much this help. one more thing. How can I ask the user to put a random number. For example: it asks you "Enter a number of games" and you put 100 and the code runs 100 times and adds up the total number for rock, paper, or scissors.

Answer (score 0):

use the FOR loop for inputing 100 times?

```
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
          (USER INPUT HERE)
          (INCREMENT SOME VARIABLES TO KEEP TRACK OF SCORES SO FAR)
    }
```

this will ask user for input and then store the result in some variable for the program to keep track of results, and it will repeat 100 times

Answer (score 0):

Use the do - while loop:

```
int i = -1;
do{
    i++;
    //get input from user
}while(i<100);
```

Beyond that your question is kind of hard to understand. It sounds like you want to store the users input into an array, then run the main game logic against that array. If that's the case, then the code in your main method will have to change to pull in the input and store it in an array and pass that array to the game logic to loop over and determine the outcome and print out the result.